# Continue playing already downloaded game with new license

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I have downloaded the game 'Assassin's Creed Valhalla' as 'one week free play'. After one week I was not able to play it. Now I bought PS Plus subscription and this game is in its catalogue and I can play it for free. But I don't want to download it again and I want to play with already downloaded game.
Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No u can't Thats a seperate Free Weekend Appliction or Game
u can download the base game for free if u have PS PLUS EXTRA but your previous game data will be there